# Storing temporary file's name and path in PHP

Tags: php, temporary-files

I am trying to create a web-based interface that would allow a user to run a specific bash script in background, gets its content and delete the temporary file that has been used to store the output. So far I have this:

```
<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="scan" class="btn btn-default">Run script</button>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['scan'])) {

   $tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "SS-");
   shell_exec('script.sh > '. $tmpfname .' &');
}

?>

<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="check-and-delete" class="btn btn-default">Check if script is running and delete the temporary file</button>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['check-and-delete'])) {
    if (shell_exec("pgrep <its process>") != '') {
        echo 'Script is running';

    } else {
        echo 'Script is NOT running';

        echo '<pre>'. file_get_contents($tmpfname) .'</pre>';
        unlink($tmpfname);
    }
}
```

However, while everything seems to work according to plan, in the end, `$tmpfname` appears to be empty resulting in failure to retrieve its content and delete it.

It goes as follows:

1. User clicks `Run script`.

   - `1.1.` A tmp file is created;
   - `1.2.` The script is ran and its output redirected to the tmp file;
2. User clicks `Check if script is running and delete the temporary file`.

   - `2.1.` A check is ran to see whether the script is still running. If the script is still running, nothing more is done but an echo;
   - `2.2.` If the script is not running (has finished), it should get the content of the tmp file and delete the file;

The problem is encountered at `2.2`. How can I store the temporary file's name/full path *permanently*?

Comment: The problem here is that the value of `$tmpfname` is not available on the second post. You could add it in the form, or better, store it in the session. PS: To make your code more general I would write: `tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(),'SS-');` instead of `tempnam("/tmp", "SS-");`.

Comment: What do you mean by "add it in the form"?

Comment: I mean: Add `$tmpfname` in the second form as a hidden field.

Comment: I'm afraid that's not the issue. `$tmpfname` is empty all before that form, once the script has finished. If I try to echo it out right after the first if statement, it's empty.

Comment: Yes, it is only defined after the first form is posted, on line 9 in your code.

Comment: I added an answer to clarify what I meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should clarify what I meant when saying: store `$tmpfname` in a session. I do not garantee this code will work, there might be other errors.

```
// always start sessions
session_start();

<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="scan" class="btn btn-default">Run script</button>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['scan'])) {

   $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "SS-");
   shell_exec('script.sh > '. $tmpfname .' &');
   // store in session
   $_SESSION['tmpfname'] = $tmpfname; 
}

?>

<form method="POST">
  <button type="submit" name="check-and-delete" class="btn btn-default">Check if script is running and delete the temporary file</button>
</form>

<?php

if (isset($_POST['check-and-delete'])) {
    if (shell_exec("pgrep <its process>") != '') {
        echo 'Script is running';

    } else {
        echo 'Script is NOT running';
        // retrieve from session
        $tmpfname = $_SESSION['tmpfname'];
        echo '<pre>'. file_get_contents($tmpfname) .'</pre>';
        unlink($tmpfname);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is working. Accepted the answer and thank you for your time. However, I am still curious about how I can achieve this within the form without a session. Could you PoC it as well if possible? Thank you.

Comment: Using a hidden form field is not a good solution, it is not reliable. But it would work like this: Add this code into the second form: `<? echo "<input type='hidden' name='tmpfname' value='$tmpfname'>"; ?>` and then pick it up while processing the second form submission as `$_POST['tmpfname']`.

Comment: Oh, right. Yes, I would stick with the session. Thanks for the heads-up again.